# how to execute the create insert selection sqlite3 query by using script with out using eof

Tags: bash, sqlite

I run the following script for creating the table by using EOF, but I want to create the all operations without using the EOF  in script how can I proceed this help me...!

```
#!/bin/bash

DB_NAME=demo
DB_TABLE=customer

sqlite3 $DB_NAME << EOF
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $DB_TABLE;

CREATE TABLE $DB_TABLE (
    "Customer_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "Customer_name" TEXT NOT NULL,"Domain_name" VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,"Status" TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO $DB_TABLE(Customer_name,Domain_name,Status) VALUES ("A","A.com","active");
INSERT INTO $DB_TABLE (Customer_name,Domain_name,Status) VALUES ( "B","B.tv","active");
INSERT INTO $DB_TABLE (Customer_name,Domain_name,Status) VALUES ( "C","C.com","active");
INSERT INTO $DB_TABLE (Customer_name,Domain_name,Status) VALUES ( "D","D.org","active");

Select * from $DB_TABLE;
EOF
```

Comment: Why not EOF? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: i want write the input in execution of code so only ...

Comment: Why? What problem would that solve?

Comment: Put the SQL in a separate file called `commands.sql`, then run `sqlite3 demo.db < commands.sql` in your main script, maybe?